# Error when remove row using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="input_modem_1" onclick="add_delete_row(this, 1,'test1' )" name="modem_id[]" value="1" /> test 1
<input type="checkbox" id="input_modem_2" onclick="add_delete_row(this, 2,'test2' )" name="modem_id[]" value="2" /> test 2
<table id="modem_list"></table>
```

And code javascript:

```
<script>
function add_delete_row(element, id, modem_name) {
    if(element.checked) {
        if(id) {
            deleteRow(id);
        }
        addRow(id, modem_name);
    } else {
        deleteRow(id);
    }
}
function addRow(id, modem_name) {
    var table = document.getElementById("modem_list");

    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var element1 = document.createElement("input");
    element1.type = "checkbox";
    cell1.appendChild(element1);

    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var element2 = document.createElement("input");
    element2.type = "hidden";
    element2.value = id;
    cell2.innerHTML = modem_name;
    cell2.appendChild(element2);
}
function deleteRow(id) {
    try {
        $('modem_list').removeChild($('modem_'+id));
        $('modem_list').removeChild($('input_modem_'+id));
    } catch(err){}
}
</script>
```

When I check on a value is result add a row, and when i uncheck this row, is result not run and it add more this, how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't using this code:
in `function addRow()` you add:

```
var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
row.className = "input_"+id; // with id is 1, 2, ...n
```

and:

```
function deleteRow(id) {
    try {
        jQuery(".input_"+id).remove();
    } catch(err){}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select element by ID using jQuery you need to use the hash symbol. That is

```
$('#modem_list')
```

not

```
$('modem_list')
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `row.setAttribute("name","modem_"+id);` after `var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);`

And replace `function deleteRow(id)` with next

```
function deleteRow(id) {
    var table = document.getElementById("modem_list");
    var rowName = 'modem_'+id;
    if (table.rows.namedItem(rowName)) {
        table.deleteRow((table.rows.namedItem(rowName).rowIndex));
    }
}
```

It works without jquery